# Ubuntu 16.04 Installer Crashes Shortly After Partitioning Disk

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, 16.04, uefi

I am trying to dual-boot Windows 10 Home and Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on a Lenovo G50-70 laptop. The computer used to have Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 14.04 LTS installed as a dual-boot with EFI. I want to do a clean install/upgrade of both operating systems with the same partition scheme as before, except a bigger Ubuntu root partition.

[image]

I have already installed Windows 10 by formatting the partition that had Windows 8 (/dev/sda4) and then installing Windows 10 onto that partition. Windows 10 works fine, and so did Ubuntu 14.04.

Then in Windows 10, I copied all the files from the ubuntu-16.04-desktop-amd64.iso into an EFI bootable USB drive, just as I did when I installed Ubuntu 14.04 back then and Windows 10 just now.

When I booted from the USB drive, I selected "Install Ubuntu" from the menu and continued on to the "Installation Type," where I chose "Something else." At the partitions screen, I chose the mount point for /dev/sda6 as /boot, /dev/sda8 as /, and /dev/sda9 as /home. This was how I had it working for Ubuntu 14.04. I chose to format /dev/sda6-9 and the first time I resized /dev/sda8 to ~32GB and as a result reduced the size of /dev/sda9. For the boot device, I chose /dev/sda6.

When I click Install Now, it takes me to the Location screen, but a few seconds later it will say the installer has crashed:[image]

When I try to report the error, it loads a live session of Ubuntu and shows this error:

> The problem cannot be reported:
>
> E:Malformed entry 2 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list (absolute Suite >Component), E:The list of sources could not be read.

Here are the contents of the file /etc/apt/sources.list:

```
deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 16.04 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20160420.1)]/ xenial main restricted
deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 16.04 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20160420.1)]/Ubuntu 14.04/ trusty main trusty restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-security main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted
```

I have tried many other things but the installer still crashes:

- not making a /boot partition
- selecting the Windows Boot Manager partition for the boot device
- selecting the hard drive as the boot device (no specific partition)
- Trying Ubuntu before installing (Ubuntu works perfectly in a live session)
- Unselecting "Download updates while Ubuntu is installing" and "Install third part software"
- deleting all the Ubuntu partitions and creating them again
- burning the ISO to a DVD and installing from the DVD
- downloading the ISO from a torrent and loading it on the USB drive
- installing while not connected to the internet
- Checking the DVD and USB drive for defects from boot menu

Other things I have done:

- disabled Secure Boot and Fast Startup in the BIOS
- checked the md5sum of the ISO files I downloaded and they do match with those provided on Ubuntu's website.

Any ideas how to fix this installer crashing problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue too. It was because I was using version of the USB Startup Disk creator that was very old, I think it was on Ubuntu 14.10. I got around the problem by booting the USB into a live session of 16.04, redownloading the 16.04 .iso image, and making a new USB Startup Disk using the updated tool in the live session. Then I rebooted onto the new disk and the installation went without a hitch.